# How to set a byte size according to incoming read bytes

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, byte

I am working on serial port programming. I have set a buffer like below

`byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];`

Now while reading it I am getting bytes less than `4096`. The response may vary so there is no fix number of bytes received. Please see below

```
//read using a Stream
  port.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);

  var receiveData = BitConverter.ToString(buffer,0, buffer.Length);
```

**Output**

```
68-81-16-01-06-3D-4A-60-0B-86-E8-46-04-68-00-00-00-00-04-02-00-00-00-39-04-22-00-00-00-2E-04-42-00-00-00-39-04-00-00-00-00-00-04-20-00-00-00-00-04-40-00-00-00-00-02-06-00-00-02-26-00-00-02-46-00-00-4E-23-16-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-........-nn
```

How can I set the response bytes exactly to its returned length?

Comment: Look at what `Read` returns.

Comment: Why do you need the fix size? Or you just need @SomeBody's solution?

Comment: Is your questions how to dimension `buffer[]` to the number of bytes received on the port prior to reading, OR, to know how many bytes have been read?

Comment: You just need to pay attention to the return value from the `Read()` method. Just like in the marked duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netcore-3.1) returns an integer, which stores how many bytes are actually received and used by your array. You can use this value in your `BitConverter`.

```
int receivedBytes = port.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);

var receiveData = BitConverter.ToString(buffer,0, receivedBytes );
```